# TypeScript Exclude an Extended Interface

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have an interface which acts as a parent of multiple child interfaces. For example:

```
interface ParentProps {
  family?: ChildA & ChildB
}
```

What I would like to do, ideally, is in certain situations exclude either `ChildA` or `ChildB` interfaces from the `family` prop.

I have tried some ideas but with errors.

```
interface FamTree extends Exclude<ParentProps['family'], ChildA> {}
```

`An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members`

When I try doing this as a type instead of an interface, I don't get any errors, but I also don't get the correct types, either.

```
type FamTree = Exclude<ParentProps['family'], ChildA>;
```

This results in `FamTree` having a type of `never` though. Not sure how best to approach this.

The end result I am looking to achieve is:

```
type FamTree = {
  family?: ChildB
}
```

Comment: If it's truly the problem that the prop is optional, try wrapping it in `Required<T>` when you extend, before Excluding

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you can `Exclude` undefined from `ParentProps['family']` and afterwards `Omit` all keys of `ChildA` from the resulting type.

```
type FamTree = Omit<Exclude<ParentProps['family'], undefined>, keyof ChildA>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=77&pln=14&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGEAWIA2ATAQVQG9hVUEAuVAZwhnAHNgBfYUSWRFDbfAIRJlUAI2p0GYZmw7R4yNAAUEMKJEUwA9gAcaQ8ogC2uAJ4B%20allyFUAMl7X%20rdhBPa0AMQSGAKqrQAvKgA8sYQADwAogAeSDgArnhQ4cqq6lq6ANoA5Eam2QC6ADSo8WBJcOBQeAB8JQDWUCaacA74BDXAQA)

---

If you want to keep shared properties, you have to `Exclude` all the keys from `A` which `B` also has.

```
type FamTree = Omit<
  Exclude<ParentProps['family'], undefined>, Exclude<keyof ChildA, keyof ChildB>
>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=100&pln=16&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGEAWIA2ATAQVQG9hVUEAuVAZwhnAHMzUlq6GxmBfYUSWIhQZs%20AEIkWAI3b0mLNrTldgvftHjI0ABQQwokbTAD2ABxqTyiALa4AngH5qWXIVQAyEa7Gq%20EO6ZoAGII1gAq%20mgAvKgA8rYQADwAogAeSDgArnhQibr6hibmANoA5Db2pQC6ADSomWA5cOBQeAB8dWkZ2bkA1lB2xnBe%20AR1-YPDLuJtbcBAA)

Comment: those will be gone too, but I assumed this is what OP wants :/

Comment: Thanks for the playground links. This is closer, but when following the first example, the `family` prop is removed from `FamTree`. I would ideally still see FamTree.family = ChildB.

Comment: well you could just wrap it inside a `{ family: ... }` https://tsplay.dev/mM4ydN

Comment: but maybe you are looking for a reusable utility type?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I'd prefer more of a reusable utility type for this. But maybe it'd be worth re-thinking the approach as a whole since this seems to be not as direct as I would have guessed.